# Vim equivalent for emacs parenthesis echo

Tags: c, vim

In emacs , when I place the cursor on a `}` the echo buffer displays the corresponding content of the matching `{`

for example:

```
if(a==b){
.
.
.
}
```

placing my cursor on `}` would display " `if (a==b).` "

Googling helped find this plugin that sounded similar 
https://github.com/vim-scripts/tEchoPair/blob/master/README
I'm new to vim. I installed the plugin but I don't get the intended result.

Is there a better way to get the matching parenthesis text? If not, how do I use this plugin ?

Comment: The README says "BUT: It actually only works for lisp-like languages.".

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for something that works with C

Comment: It shows matching `}` and `)` for `{` and `(` in vim 7.2 without any plugins. I didnt get what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to code a tiny script `ShowMatchBrace.vim` (that you can put it in your `.vimrc`) which displays the matched line for "**`}`**" and "**`)`**" during normal mode. (You are free to do whatever you want with it)

```sh
autocmd! CursorMoved * call <SID>MatchBraces()

"This variable is for redrawing the cmd-line"
if !exists("s:brace")
   let s:brace=0
endif

function! s:MatchBraces()
   let l:currentPos=getpos('.')
   if getline('.')[col('.') - 1] =~# '\v\}|\)'
      let s:brace=1 
      normal! % 
      if getline('.')[col('.')-1] =~# '\v\{|\('  
         echo getline('.')
      else      
         echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg "No match found for }|)" | echohl None
      endif     
   elseif s:brace ==# 1
      call feedkeys("\<c-l>")
      let s:brace=0
   endif
   call setpos('.',l:currentPos)
endfunction
```

### [Demo<sup>1</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6OOu.gif)

[image: Demo]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The Demo was before adding little changes to the code to include ")" case but it behaves exactly the same way as "}".</sub>